# Inequality between the expected value of the absolute value of a random variable and the expect value of the variable itself.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, reference-request, expected-value

Amid one exercise I am solving, it would be extremely helpful to guarantee that the inequality

$$ E[ \, |X| \, ] \leqslant | \, E[X] \, | $$

holds. So, essentially, I would like to know under what conditions (if any) is this inequality true (or, in other words, what conditions do I have to impose to the r.v. $X$ (if any) such that this inequality holds).

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Why would you expect this in general?  There are plenty of non-zero random variables with mean $0$, for instance.

Comment: @lulu I don't expect it to be true, but I've see my professor using it on one exercise were there were pratically no assumptions on the random variables in question, which made me wonder when this inequality is actually true. To be a bit more detailed, this inequality has been used (without justification) in the following context: given that $X_1,X_2,\dots$ are independent r.v. and $E[X_n] = \mu$ (no information on $\mu), \forall n \in \Bbb N$, consider $ S_n = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i $. The inequality has been used here, to guarantee that $E[\, | S_n | \,] \leqslant| \, E[S_n] \, |$.

Comment: Well, without some very strong assumptions, this doesn't generally hold.  Say $X_i$ is the binary variable $\pm 1$ with equal probability.  Then $E[|S_n|]>0$ but $E[S_n]=0$.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your overview. I will have to argue this with my professor, I guess. Your counter-example will reveal itself usefull, I am sure.

Comment: Note:  there was an error in what I wrote initially (now corrected).  It is certainly true that $E[|X_i|]=1$ but you can't read off $E[|S_n|]$ so easily.  It is, however, clear that it is $>0$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$0\leq E(|X|-X)=E(|X|)-E(X)$ and equality implies $|X|-X=0$ with pb 1, or $\Pr(X\geq 0)=1.$ Similarly $0\leq E(|X|+X)=E(|X|)+E(X)$ and equality implies $|X|+X=0$ with pb $1,$ or $\Pr(X\leq 0)=1.$ Now $E(|X|)\leq |E(X)|$ implies $E(|X|)= |E(X)|$ since we have always  $E(|X|)\geq |E(X)|.$ Therefore $E(|X|)\leq |E(X)|$ holds if and only if  either $\Pr(X\geq 0)=1$ or $\Pr(X\leq 0)=1.$

Comment: Yes, yes, you are right. But implicitely a statement involving $E(X)$ supposes that $E(|X|)<\infty$ and this covers the 'if and only if."